# Convert frozen model(.pb) to savedmodel

Tags: tensorflow

Recently I tried to convert the model (tf1.x) to the saved_model, and followed the official [migrate document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate). However in my use case, most of model in my hand or tensorflow model zoo usually is pb file, and according to the [official document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#a_graphpb_or_graphpbtxt) says that

> There is no straightforward way to upgrade a raw Graph.pb file to TensorFlow 2.0, but if you have a "Frozen graph" (a tf.Graph where the variables have been turned into constants), then it is possible to convert this to a concrete_function using v1.wrap_function:

But I still do not understand how to converted to [saved_model format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model).

Answer (score 3):

in TF1 mode:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants

def convert_pb_to_server_model(pb_model_path, export_dir, input_name='input:0', output_name='output:0'):
    graph_def = read_pb_model(pb_model_path)
    convert_pb_saved_model(graph_def, export_dir, input_name, output_name)


def read_pb_model(pb_model_path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(pb_model_path, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        return graph_def


def convert_pb_saved_model(graph_def, export_dir, input_name='input:0', output_name='output:0'):
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)

    sigs = {}
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
        g = tf.get_default_graph()
        inp = g.get_tensor_by_name(input_name)
        out = g.get_tensor_by_name(output_name)

        sigs[signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY] = \
            tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
                {"input": inp}, {"output": out})

        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                             [tag_constants.SERVING],
                                             signature_def_map=sigs)
        builder.save()
```

in TF2 mode:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph
from tensorflow.lite.python.util import run_graph_optimizations, get_grappler_config
import numpy as np
def frozen_keras_graph(func_model):
    frozen_func, graph_def = convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph(func_model)

    input_tensors = [
        tensor for tensor in frozen_func.inputs
        if tensor.dtype != tf.resource
    ]
    output_tensors = frozen_func.outputs
    graph_def = run_graph_optimizations(
        graph_def,
        input_tensors,
        output_tensors,
        config=get_grappler_config(["constfold", "function"]),
        graph=frozen_func.graph)

    return graph_def


def convert_keras_model_to_pb():

    keras_model = train_model()
    func_model = tf.function(keras_model).get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec(keras_model.inputs[0].shape, keras_model.inputs[0].dtype))
    graph_def = frozen_keras_graph(func_model)
    tf.io.write_graph(graph_def, '/tmp/tf_model3', 'frozen_graph.pb')

def convert_saved_model_to_pb():
    model_dir = '/tmp/saved_model'
    model = tf.saved_model.load(model_dir)
    func_model = model.signatures["serving_default"]
    graph_def = frozen_keras_graph(func_model)
    tf.io.write_graph(graph_def, '/tmp/tf_model3', 'frozen_graph.pb')
```

Or:

```py
def convert_saved_model_to_pb(output_node_names, input_saved_model_dir, output_graph_dir):
    from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph

    output_node_names = ','.join(output_node_names)

    freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph=None, input_saver=None,
                              input_binary=None,
                              input_checkpoint=None,
                              output_node_names=output_node_names,
                              restore_op_name=None,
                              filename_tensor_name=None,
                              output_graph=output_graph_dir,
                              clear_devices=None,
                              initializer_nodes=None,
                              input_saved_model_dir=input_saved_model_dir)


def save_output_tensor_to_pb():
    output_names = ['StatefulPartitionedCall']
    save_pb_model_path = '/tmp/pb_model/freeze_graph.pb'
    model_dir = '/tmp/saved_model'
    convert_saved_model_to_pb(output_names, model_dir, save_pb_model_path)
```

Comment: Please add expiation.

Comment: You save my day, thanks!!!

For anyone who use tensorflow version > 2.0,
"import tensorflow as tf" should be replaced by 
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

Comment: How do I know input and output name?

Comment: @secsilm You can use ```saved_model_cli show --dir``` check the .pb information.

Comment: `ValueError: The name 'input' refers to an Operation, not a Tensor. Tensor names must be of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>".` at `inp = g.get_tensor_by_name(input_name)`

Comment: @zeeshankhan oh,you can use ```input:0``` for input of model

Comment: I have a saved_model (.pb file + assets + variables directories) that I can load using "loaded = tf.saved_model.load("mobilenet/1/") " in tensorflow 2.3. How can I convert and save to disk it as a single frozen model?

Comment: @Fisa See my updated code. There are two ways to save it.

Comment: My frozen TF1 graph (that I want to convert to saved model) has the following tensors: https://ghostbin.com/MlDHG what do I specify as my input tensors using your script?

Comment: @lepton do you known what is input tensor’s name.if you known, just use `convert_pb_to_server_model`  to do it.  example:  `convert_pb_to_server_model('/tmp/pb_path','/tmp/save_path',input_name='myname:0', output_name='myout:0')`

Comment: @Boluoyu When I use get_operations() on the frozen graph, it seems to show more than one input tensor. See here: https://ghostbin.com/lhDCb

Comment: @lepton  `predict_signature_def` accept a dict param ,so if there is multi input tensor, it works. ex:`inp1 = g.get_tensor_by_name('input1:0')  inp2 = g.get_tensor_by_name('input1:0') inputs = {'input1':inp1,'input2':inp2}  tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
                inputs, {"output": out})`

Comment: I have a detection model with multiple outputs like `'num_detections': name: "StatefulPartitionedCall:5", 'raw_detection_boxes': name: "StatefulPartitionedCall:6",...`. I only want to use 4 of theses outputs, how do I define the `output_node_names` correct, so that the unneeded outputs get stripped out of the graph?

Comment: @ai2ys  It is the same thing as input. ex:https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MYtz8Qaj45jZo6xH4gPewRXkRCyCMjsS#scrollTo=Qhe1_Cj4fbdA

Comment: @Boluoyu
Unfortunately, I am not able to access your link, because of access rights. Could you please check.

Comment: @ai2ys  Sorry,this is the first time to use Colab .https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MYtz8Qaj45jZo6xH4gPewRXkRCyCMjsS?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @Boluoyu. Does it work the same with TF 2?

Comment: @ai2ys  TF2 is a little different from TF1.In TF2 mode ,you can refer to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure whether my understanding is correct, so I also post what I learnt:

If anyone want to migrate tf1.x to tf2.x, please followed the [official post](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) first.

In tensorflow 2.0, tf.train.Saver and [freeze_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29253) was already replaced by [saved_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model).

And if anyone want to convert pb model from tf1.x into saved_model, you can followed @Boluoyu answer. But if your run-time environment is above tf2.0, you can use following code:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf 
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants

def covert_pb_to_server_model(pb_model_path, export_dir, input_name='input', output_name='output'):
    graph_def = read_pb_model(pb_model_path)
    covert_pb_saved_model(graph_def, export_dir, input_name, output_name)


def read_pb_model(pb_model_path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(pb_model_path, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        return graph_def


def covert_pb_saved_model(graph_def, export_dir, input_name='input', output_name='output'):
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)

sigs = {}
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    inp = g.get_tensor_by_name(input_name)
    out = g.get_tensor_by_name(output_name)

    sigs[signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY] = \
        tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
            {"input": inp}, {"output": out})

    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                         [tag_constants.SERVING],
                                         signature_def_map=sigs)
    builder.save()
```